# Cohomology of Eilenberg Maclane space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

In a book on spectral sequences that I am reading, it is stated, without proof, that $H^i(K(\mathbb{Z},2);H^0(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z}))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ for even $i$ and $0$ for odd $i$. This is supposed to arise from the cohomology Serre spectral sequence for the pathspace fibration $K(\mathbb{Z},1) \to P \to K(\mathbb{Z},2)$, wherein $E_2^{i,0} = H^i(K(\mathbb{Z},2);H^0(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z}))$.

Unless there is something about the space $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ that I am not aware of, I don't see how the statement holds true. $H^0(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z})$ is of course isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, but I do know the cohomology groups of $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$. Does anyone know how to calculate the cohomology groups of $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ (with integer coefficients)? Is that how I am supposed to approach this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since the infinite complex projective space is a K(Z,2), you can compute its cohomology. This is very easy to do if you use cellular cohomology.

Comment: If you want to use the spectral sequence, then just write down the E2 page, use the fact that it converges to the cohomology of a point and proceed as usual with a spectral sequence (if you do not know what "as usual" means, then read the book by McCleary on the subject)

Comment: (Probably this example or one just like it is treated in detail in Bott+Tu's book on differential forms, so that is also a good reference for how to use the spectral sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute this from the described pathspace spectral sequence, using the fact that $P$ is contractible so every nontrivial term in the spectral sequence except the $(0,0)$ term must eventually disappear.  Since $H^*(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes unless $*=0$ or $*=1$, the only possible nontrivial differentials on the spectral sequence are the $d_2$ differentials, and they must give isomorphisms $H^i(K(\mathbb{Z},2);H^1(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z}))\to H^{i+2}(K(\mathbb{Z},2);H^0(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z}))$ for each $i\geq 0$.  Since $H^1(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z})\cong H^0(K(\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, this just says that $H^i(K(\mathbb{Z},2);\mathbb{Z})\cong H^{i+2}(K(\mathbb{Z},2);\mathbb{Z})$ for each $i\geq 0$.  Since $H^0(K(\mathbb{Z},2);\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $H^1(K(\mathbb{Z},2);\mathbb{Z})=0$ (by Hurewicz), the desired result follows by induction on $i$.

Comment: You do not need Hurewicz: that zero follows from convergence, no?

Comment: Sure, you can also get the values of $H^0$ and $H^1$ from the convergence because there are no differentials that can hit them.